# App store review - can project contain "beta" in its name even if it's not beta?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My project contains the word "beta" in name, but has nothing to do with beta. Renaming project is kind of tedious so I wonder if ios app store may reject my app due to that fact? Should I keep trying to rename the project?

What is your opinion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If look at the AppStore you'll [find some apps](https://fnd.io/#/us/search?mediaType=ios&term=beta) the uses the word beta without being beta-apps.

So if it's clear enough that your app is not a beta app, it should get accepted :)